# SWI Prolog font-size settings

Tags: swi-prolog

I can reach a solution as a result of the rules I created through prolog. but the font size looks quite small. it's really hard to read. how can i enlarge it?

[image: SWI Prolog Screen]

Alternative Link: https://hizliresim.com/vaq1aO

Comment: just got to "settings" and then "font" there you can choose your font + size

Comment: I thought I would correct the font size with prolog code. The solution is simple. thank you.

Comment: The prolog shell does not know anything about the graphical window it's running in. It's just text mode.